# Automatically call .what() on unhandled C++ exception in the Visual Studio Debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

It's very annoying to always put "(std::exception*)0x123..." into the Watch window to get to the exception message when the debugger hits an unhandled exception in C++.

Is there a better way?

Maybe I can use a more dynamic watch entry that gets the current exception address automatically?

Or maybe there is an exception hook that does not interfere with the MSVC debugger's exception handling?

Or a debugger extension?

Comment: If the exception is your own then you’d have to add it to Debug->Windows->ExceptionSettings. Although really id recommend handling them and logging in that case. Otherwise IIRC any exceptions enabled there should present a dialogue box when thrown. Alternatively I have a feeling that exceptions show up in the program’s log so it’d be worth checking there.

Comment: Hard to imagine how this turned into a practical problem.  Just eliminate the need for what() completely, Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and tick "C++ Exceptions".  The debugger now automatically breaks when the exception is thrown, even if it will be caught, so you can see why.  But if you use exceptions for flow control then repeatedly having to press F5 gets tedious as well.

Comment: @HansPassant The Visual Studio IDE opens a little window but does not allow to explore the exception object at all. The only information that the window gives you is the type of exception, the address of the throw statement, and the address of the exception object. So the OP seems right, we have to copy/paste the type and address in the watch window to be able to see inside the exception, which looks like something an advanced IDE like VS ought to do for you!
From my empirical experience, it displays garbage, so we have to let the debugger reach some catch statement to see the message.